# Passing 2D numpy array to C++ for PDE integration

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy, swig, cython

I have a code that is implementing finite differences method for integration of a certain partial differential equation. As I want to boost the code, I would like to pass the 2D numpy array from my Python code to a C++ function that will implement the integrator. I have read here few questions on this subject, but I wanted to ask here what should be more suitable for this mission, SWIG or Cython ? (or a different method?)

Comment: Have you also looked into [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/python/doc/)? I'm looking at a similar problem right now, I might try to blog about it if I get the time.

Comment: A comprehensive guide here: https://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/interfacing_with_c/interfacing_with_c.html

Comment: It depends entirely on how you have implemented the C++ method. Are you using Boost already? Because then Boost.Python will probably be simplest? Are you going to implement it from scratch? Because then perhaps the enhanced syntax of Cython might help. Is it an already implemented library? Then it can be a toss up betwee any of Cython/Swig/Boost.Python.

Comment: @BeRecursive I haven't implemented yet the C++ method, so I wanted to check first what way should I pursue for this mission. As I understand I should start from Cython, and I started to learn Cython through the reference that  YXD gave me here. Thanks guys for the tips!